# How to set collection_select with default multiple selected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use `:multiple => true` to define a collection_select with multiple and use javascript to fill it, but how can I set `all option default been selected` with a simple setting on collection_select? or it need to use javascript to accomplish?

```
<%= collection_select('', :beacon_uuid, [], :id, :beacon_uuid , {:prompt => true }, :multiple => true, :size => 3 , :id => 'beacon_uuid_dropdown', :selected => '' ) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `collection_select` to set the selected you can pass an array of selected ids to the `selected` key `:selected => selected_ids` but then you'll have to initialize the collection here not through javascript.

If the options are added through javascript they you'll need to add the `selected` attribute for every option as you created it (using javascript)